# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException Writing to Azure Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I am getting a **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException** exception occasionally when writing to Azure Queue, but do not understand what this exception means and how to avoid it.

From my telemetry, I can see this write is taking a long time, about 30-40 seconds before failing.

I am writing to the queue like so:

```
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("string content example");
await queue.AddMessageAsync(message);
```

**Does anyone know what this Exception means?**

Here is the full stack trace, it does not give me much info

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 50)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   121) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   Microsoft.Community.Data.Providers.AzureQueueProvider+d__1.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   D:\a\1\s\Microsoft.Community\Microsoft.Community.Data\Providers\AzureQueueProvider.csMicrosoft.Community.Data,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 60) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   Microsoft.Community.Web.Repositories.AzureMLRecommendationsRepository+d__5.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Community.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Community.Web, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   D:\a\1\s\Microsoft.Community\Microsoft.Community.Web\Repositories\AzureMLRecommendationsRepository.csMicrosoft.Community.Web,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 89) Inner
>   exception System.Net.WebException handled at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync:
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 54)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.b__2f
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Queue\CloudQueue.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   2587) at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   299)

Comment: If this is new as of today you may be affected by the outage currently impacting Azure:

9/4/2018 - 11:58 EST: "Engineers are in the process of restoring power to affected data center devices. Resources in South Central and potentially other regions may experience impact. Please refer to your portal, http://status.azure.com   and/or Twitter for updates."

Comment: Thanks! @JoshCarlisle